# Example of two subspaces of $\mathbb R$ with different numbers of cut-points

Tags: general-topology

Can anybody give an example of two subspaces of  $\mathbb R_{usual}$  with different numbers of cut-points?

Comment: $\{0\}$ and $[0,1]$.

Comment: @DavidMitra: Well, it depends on definition. I would think that empty space is connected.

Comment: @user87690 I assumed "no cut points" was allowed.

Comment: @DavidMitra: Oh sorry, you are right. :-)

Comment: @DavidMitra:  Thank you, one more question: Are two spaces with different numbers of non-cut-points not homeomorphic?

Comment: The property of being a cut point is preserved under homeomorphisms.

Comment: So, the answer is positive?

Answer (score 4):

Every connected subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ is either an interval which has continuum many cut-points or a point which has no cut-points. As studiosus noted, empty set is also connected subspace and has also no cut-points.

As David Mitra noted this gives the example since number of cutpoints of one-point space is zero.

For the second question. Two spaces with different number of cut-points are not homeomorphic. As David Mitra says, if $f: X \to Y$ is homeomorphism and $x ∈ X$ is a cut-point then $f(x)$ is also cut-point. So if $C$ is the set of all cut-points of $X$ then $f[C]$ are cut-points in $Y$ so $Y$ as at least as much cut-points as $X$. And by symmetric argument the other inequality also holds.

Comment: Thank you, one more question: Are two spaces with different numbers of non-cut-points not homeomorphic?

Comment: @user136592 See edited answer.

Comment: For the sake of completeness: There is one more connected subset that you did not mention: The empty set. It does not have any cut points either.